# Is it possible to create session programatically in aws-amplify using id, refresh, access Tokens

Tags: aws-amplify

I am using aws-amplify for authentication, but I want to create session programmatically using tokens, It seems currently its not possible with aws-amplify. Do any one has better solution.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: For now I manually check token validity before api request and refresh the tokens